# Printing JSON data in React JS through mapping

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have this link https://api.covid19api.com/countries, which holds the "Country", "Slug", and "ISO2" of several countries. I want to display, only the "Country" value in  tag.I wrote the following code

```
function App() {

  const [countries,setCountries] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchData(){
      const data = fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/countries').then(resp => resp.json());
      setCountries(data)
    }
    fetchData();
  },[])

  if(!countries){
    return(
      <h3>Loading.....</h3>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {
          countries.map(() => <h1>{countries.Country}</h1>)
        }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but, it was giving the following error

> TypeError: countries.map is not a function

Could anyone please say the correct way to do it

Comment: Probably because countries does not exist yet during rendering. Do something like `countries && countries.ma(...)`. You can do a console.log just before the return at one point countries will be undefined then will later be defined after the API request is done.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just missing an `await` before `setCountries`.

```
const data = await fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/countries').then(resp => resp.json());
      setCountries(data)
```

Also, I think, it's better to initialise `countries` with an empty array here in this case.

`const [countries,setCountries] = React.useState([]);`

Comment: That is only one of the problems. No default empty array is another as well as incorrect use of `map()`

Answer (score 2):

**3 issues**

1 => You are not using await

2 => You are not passing any parameter in the map method

3 => Response is an array, So you need to make your state an array.

Updated Code.

```
function App() {

  const [countries,setCountries] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchData(){
      const data = await fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/countries').then(resp => resp.json());
      setCountries(data)
    }
    fetchData();
  },[])

  if(!countries){
    return(
      <h3>Loading.....</h3>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {
          countries.map((data) => <h1>{data.Country}</h1>)
        }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Third issue is `countries` is not an array on initial render. Modifying to `React.useState([]);` would set empty array as default

Comment: You are right , I just checked the API. Let me fix that

Comment: @RahulDwivedi Setting empty array as default value for `countries` solves that

Comment: @RahulDwivedi I mean setting default using `React.useState([]);`. Syntax you used makes no sense

Answer (score -1):

You have had await keyword with async. The word 'async' before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise and the keyword await makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result. So it will be something like this

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const data = await fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/countries").then(
        resp => resp.json()
      );
      setCountries(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

This is my codesandbox link if wanna check - https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-lewin-7wwn9